# Scraping a website with a form

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from this site:
https://action.labour.org.uk/page/content/council-cuts-calculator

I plan to loop through a list of postcodes and collect information on each of them.

I have tried using the requests module like so:

```
import requests
url = 'https://action.labour.org.uk/page/content/council-cuts-calculator'
payload =   {'firstname': 'james',
            'email': 'myemailaddress',
            'zip': 'WS13 6QG',
            'custom_15452': 'no'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
results_text = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(results_text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.get_text())
```

The code runs without an error but does not seem to pass the information to the form, or at least the printed part does not contain the same information as if I enter the same information manually. I suspect that it might be because the it's using javascript rather than a request but don't know how to tell.

Can anyone let me know what method to use to get the information I'm after, a sample result is below. Also, more generally how can you tell whether a website form requires requests.get requests.post or some other method?

> In LICHFIELD, your council will have £68 less to spend on your household by 2020 than they had in 2010.
>
> Under the Tories some of the most deprived areas in the country are hit the hardest, while Tory councils are given a better deal. On average, Tory councils will have £128 less to spend per household, while Labour councils are hit four times harder – losing £524.

Comment: The form submit makes a GET request to an URL like https://action.labour.org.uk/page/content/council-cuts-calculator?firstname=aa&email=bb&zip=123&custom-15452=no.

Comment: You could simply make a GET request to https://stats-microapi-production.herokuapp.com/index.php?campaign=1&pc=WS136QG with appropriate zip code.

Comment: First form submit uses `https://action.labour.org.uk/page/signup/local-cuts-calculator` for signup which done by javascript. Next if you want to scrap data dynamic data, you can try selenium. Its quite good.

Comment: Or simply look at the javascript function `getAndShowCuts` in the source and implement the same in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like when you first make the POST request, there is also another immediate GET request made to https://stats-microapi-production.herokuapp.com to fetch the data you are looking for.

Turns out you could just make a GET request to
https://stats-microapi-production.herokuapp.com/index.php?campaign=1&pc=WS136QG with appropriate pin code without first having to make that POST request.

Just for future reference, it is helpful to analyze network packets your browser deals with using [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy) or other alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, using a work system so can't install mitmproxy myself but useful to know such a thing exists.